# glacier restore status from aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am restoring a directory and its subfolders from `glacier` and can see it restoring in the gui but not get the status using the below in the cli. The  is the specific id of the folder that is being restored. Thank you :).

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket <bucket> \
--key s3://<bucket>/<directory> --profile <profile>

An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can only lookup a single object in the directory, not the directory itself. Thank you :).